# amasty delivery data extension displaying date and time twice magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, amasty

We have installed extension on fresh magento 1.9.3 store,

module name `Amasty_Deliverydate`

on the checkout page its been displaying twice

as per the image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using our extension.

This is not a common problem, and it is hard to understand the course of it from the screenshot only. It might be a conflict with some other module or problems with your theme.

Please, create a ticket (https://amasty.com/contacts/) and we will investigate the problem or you.